# Debugging and profiling web workers

Tags: javascript, debugging, profiling, web-worker

I am running computations e.g. path-finding in web workers.  This can take several seconds and I want to optimise it.  Chrome seems to be about 3x faster for my current code, but where the time is spent or why I have no insight into.

Generally, how can you debug web workers?

How can you profile web workers?

(Firefox and Chrome)

Answer (score 4):

In Chrome you may open web worker source in Sources > Workers and get full interface to prifile.
Profiling in Firefox - no idea.
And http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/08/25/web-workers-errors-and-debugging/

Comment: I believe what Chrome does is run the worker in an iframe, meaning it runs inside your main thread effectively.  This skews profiling.

Comment: For a working description on Web Worker profiling see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22511158/how-to-profile-web-workers-in-chrome/24785355#24785355