# Chrome developer tool how to profile webworkers?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, web-worker, chrome-debugging

I looked at [How to profile web workers in Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22511158/how-to-profile-web-workers-in-chrome) etc but the advise there is for older versions of chrome and now seem to be dated.

How can I profile the memory of a web worker (take snapshots and compare them) in chrome >86 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Memory panel, you have to select which JavaScript VM you want to profile:

[image]